# PHP for each for $_POST

Tags: php, post, for-loop, foreach

Sorry for the noob question, I'm kinda stuck.

I have the following HTML form. The form can be cloned as many as possible.

```
    <div class="form">
       <input type="text"  name="user_name_1"  >
       <input type="email" name="user_email_1"  >
    </div>

   <div class="form">
       <input type="text"  name="user_name_2"    >
       <input type="email"  name="user_email_2"  >
   </div>

  <div id="submit-form">
      <input type='hidden' name='user_email'>
      <input type="submit"  value="Submit" />
      <input type="button" class="button" id="cloneForm" value="Clone" />
  </div>
```

The name field increments every time when clone button is clicked. In PHP How do I use $_POST to loop through the fields to create unique accounts for each form div?

SAMPLE PHP

```
   for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) { 
      $name = $_POST['user_name_'+$i];
      $mail = $_POST['user_email_'+$i];

   }
```

Comment: `+` -> `.` to concate a string

Answer (score 5):

use html:

`name="user_email[]"`

now  `$_POST['user_email']` will be an array. downside though is that you cannot control the index of the array.

so to loop through the array:

```
foreach ($_POST['user_email'] as $email) { 
   print $email
}
```

or to get the first item: `$_POST['user_email'][0]`

### Your quick codefix:

The bug in your code is not your HTML though, its php:
To combine/concat strings together in php use `.`, not `+`

```
for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) { 
      $name = $_POST['user_name_'.$i];
      $mail = $_POST['user_email_'.$i];
}
```

for reference:

- http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php

Comment: @user123 ... This is the best way. By using this as long as you have the exact same `user_name`/`user_email` combo you will be successful.

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning that he should count the array for the for loop.

Comment: @sark9012 not if he used a `foreach` on the newly created `user_email` and `user_name` arrays wouldn't need the `for` as long as they were exactly the same length. It would probably be wise to do a check of the length before those, but most likely unnecessary.

Comment: w3schools is not a reference site. Please never visit it, and never link to it! Real reference is here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php

Comment: @atornblad w3schools is good enough to reference in most cases. They give a very basic overview and have been used many times to get a basic understanding. For a more extended search they may come across php.net for an extended explanation.

Comment: @CayceK agreed if using foreach! Joel was using a for loop initially when I commented on the question, he's since updated!

Comment: Please dont keep flaming about what website to use for reference. Both are proper just, add more references if you think its not complete.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<div class="form">
   <input type="text"  name="user_name[]"  >
   <input type="email" name="user_email[]"  >
</div>

<div class="form">
   <input type="text"  name="user_name[]"    >
   <input type="email"  name="user_email[]"  >
```

```
<div id="submit-form">
  <input type='hidden' name='user_email[]'>
  <input type="submit"  value="Submit" />
  <input type="button" class="button" id="cloneForm" value="Clone" />
```

in PHP code:

```
$val1 = $_POST['user_name'];
$val2 = $_POST['user_email'];

foreach ($val1 as $key=> $value) { 
  $name = $val1[$key]; // or  $value;
  $mail = $val2[$key];
}
```

Comment: This is confusing using the `foreach` as you are.. In reality you should not include the `$key=>$value` as you have it should instead be `$key` this way you can use the key word `$value` in this loop if you so choose AND you avoid wasting unused variables. In this case you use `$val1[$key]` which is the same as `$value` and do not ever use (or plan to) `$value` though the "wasted" variable isn't that big of a deal it is still something that is unnecessary and could create confusion. "Where did that variable go?"

Comment: i did code in a very simple way and marked for user as he can use any one variable. Questionnaire looked as beginner. So i put that code.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist to use names like this ("user_name[]" is much better) and there is no DELETE of the rows,
here is how you can access them:

```
 for ($i=0; $i < 100; $i++) {
      if(!isset($_POST['user_name_'+$i])){
          break;// stop the cycle when there are no more rows
      }
      $name = $_POST['user_name_'+$i];
      $mail = $_POST['user_email_'+$i];

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know the number of entries before, you need to check this at runtime. Loop through the `$_POST` array and look for keys starting with **user_name_**

Try `foreach ... as`:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => value) {
    // Is this a user name?
    if (strpos($key, 'user_name_') === 0) {
        // Get the index part
        $index = substr($key, 10);

        // Get the expected POST key for email address
        $emailKey = "user_email_$index";

        // TODO: read $value and $_POST[$emailKey]
        // TODO: stuff...
    }
}
```